# Htaccess URLRewrite to another map

Tags: php, .htaccess, dictionary, url-rewriting, internal

When i go to {url}/klanten/home/ or {url}/klanten/logout/ a 500 Internal Server Error come.

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^klanten/([^/]+)/?$ klanten/$1.php [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^error/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ error.php?type=$1&error=$2&file=$3&from=$4 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^email/([^/]+)/?$ email.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

The map 'klanten' exists and the file home.php and logout.php exists too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule is wrong, it leads to an indefinite redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^klanten/([^/]+)/?$ klanten/$1.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

`/klanten/logout/` will lead to `/klanten/logout.php` which in turn will be rewritten again and again.

You could add the dot to the character class to avoid that so that only urls without a dot get rewritten:

```
RewriteRule ^klanten/([^/\.]+)/?$ klanten/$1.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

or you just add the conditions that existing files and directories do not get rewritten (obviously the better solution...):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^klanten/([^/]+)/?$ klanten/$1.php [L,QSA,NC]
```