# Htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dictionary, switch-statement

After asking this question [Htaccess URLRewrite to another map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442962/htaccess-urlrewrite-to-another-map/12443000#12443000)
That works great, but now i want to add an extra 'map', but that don't work.

My .htaccess file now:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /v2/404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /v2/505.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^error/([^/]+)/?$ error.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^email/([^/]+)/?$ email.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^activate/([^/]+)/?$ activate.php?code=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^werknemer/([^/]+)/?$ werknemer/$1.php [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^klanten/([^/]+)/?$ klanten/$1.php [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Always the last wont work, now RewriteRule ^klanten/ don't work, and when i do RewriteRule ^werknemer/ after RewriteRule ^klanten/, RewriteRule ^klanten/ works but RewriteRule ^werknemer/ not.

How to fix this?

Thanks!
Wouter0100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to duplicate the 2 conditions again. `RewriteCond`'s are only applied to the immediately following `RewriteRule`, so you need to duplicate the conditions if they are to be applied to more than one rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^werknemer/([^/]+)/?$ werknemer/$1.php [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^klanten/([^/]+)/?$ klanten/$1.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

Maybe you need it for your last rule as well:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [L]
```

That checks if a trailing slash exists, and to remove it before seeing if adding the `php` to the end produces an existing file.