# htaccess Rewrite Rules issue

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am struggling with my RewriteRules. I want to handle requests as follows:

Requests that match example.com/2 (domain/any number), should be handled by my cdn. So I wrote this, but it does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(\d+)*$ ../../cdn.example.com/public_html/l/i.php?id=$1
```

My server replies with 400 Bad Request and nothing more.

The following worked for me on an older xampp installation.

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ ./e/$1.php
```

(Now I am using linux apache2.) 
I tried to solve the problem by using [Jon Lin's script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572613/htaccess-rewriterule), but this gives me 400 or 404.

Comment: That rule implements an internal rewrite to a _folder_ named `cdn.example.com`... Are you certain that is what you want? I do not see a connection to a CDN in that case...

Comment: My WebApp consists out of my main Website (example.com) and my cdn (cdn.example.com). Example.com is using html documents which are saved in cdn.example.com.
A js plugin loads contents from cdn.example.com (pure html) and merges it with the example.com page.
[example](https://motz.ml/)

Comment: [Moved the question to a new webpage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375308/htaccess-rewrite-rules-issu), as jww proposed.

Comment: I still don't understand the connection between a local path and a CDN. But whatever...

Comment: My Webserver is configured to work with many Domains.
I have a path for each domain and my lite documents are saved in the cdn directory. I don't want to copy them to my main dir